# Visibility polygon and linear time algorithm

Tags: computational-geometry

From a quick research on algorithms finding the visibility polygon of a point inside a polygon I found out that this can be done in O(n) time if the polygon has no holes.

**What I'm trying to find is the set of points inside a polygon from which the whole polygon is visible.**

My main question is :

**Is this possible in O(n) time and space?**

I know I'm gonna explain this poorly and I'll try to upload pictures later but here's some of my thoughts.

The idea I have is to go around the boundary of the polygon. The neighbooring points of the polygon form lines with a certain angle with respect to the x-axis. If the next line's angle is greater than the previous one , extending these two lines , towards the inside of the polygon, we get the visibility polygon at this point.

Repeating this process we find several pairs of lines that split the polygon we are making and increase the polygon edges by 1 each time.

If the polygon has n points , going around its boundary requires a for 1 -> n loop . That makes my running time " n times the process inside the loop " .

The process inside the loop alters the polygon made up to this point taking into account the 2 new lines that cross it. To find the new polygon I have to test the new lines with every line of the polygon. That means another for loop from 1 to the number of the increasing polygon edges. Since the edges increase in time this algorithm is somewhere between O(n) and O(n^2).

Going around the boundary and finding the points of the final polygon is definitely necessary. That makes me think that an O(n) algorithm may not be possible.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not trying to contradict the result. I'm sorry for my English. I'm just wondering if a linear time solution is possible. I'll say one more thing in case I've been misunderstood. I'm not trying to find the visibility polygon of a certain point inside the polygon but the set of points that can see the whole polygon.

Comment: I discarded my comment before I saw yours :)

Comment: What you are looking for is called the "visibility kernel".

Comment: Preparata et Shamos indeed report the possibility to build it in optimal time Theta(n).

Comment: @YvesDaoust Wow, I'm getting the perfect google results right now. Thanks Yves.